# Вывести переменную с текстом без кавычек

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot

Вывожу несколько строк в цикле в сообщение телеграм бота.

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `sum` FROM `base` WHERE `rain`='".$rain."'");
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      $msg .= sprintf("%-10s %5s\n", $array[0], $array[1]);
    apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => $msg));
```

Хочу что бы этот список выходил в inline кнопках, не понимаю как это сделать.
Пытался вывести это в keybord так.

```
 while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    $format .= sprintf("['%-10s %5s'],", $array[0], $array[1]);

apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => $msg, 'reply_markup' => array(
        'keyboard' => [$format],
        'one_time_keyboard' => true,
        'resize_keyboard' => true)));
```

Лог выдает вот что

> [25-Nov-2017 14:37:04 Europe/Moscow] Request has failed with error
>   400: Bad Request: can't parse keyboard button: KeyboardButton should
>   be a String or an Object

Кнопки inline должны быть в таком формате:

```
array( 'keyboard' => [['key1'],['key2'],['key3']],
            'one_time_keyboard' => true,
            'resize_keyboard' => true)
```

у меня же он получается типа такого

```
array( 'keyboard' => ["['key1'],['key2'],['key3'],"],
                'one_time_keyboard' => true,
                'resize_keyboard' => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо собирания строки:

```
while ($array1 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
   $format .= sprintf("['%-10s %5s'],", $array[0], $array[1]);
```

Собирайте массив:

```
while ($array1 = mysql_fetch_array($query))  
   $format[] = [sprintf("'%-10s %5s',", $array[0], $array[1])];
```

Comment: А в `'keyboard' => array(array($format))` так и оставить?

Comment: Вам виднее, один array, полагаю стоит убрать)

Comment: Простите я там немного ошибся, щас покажу как должны выглядеть inline

Comment: Стало быть `'keyboard' => $format` вам подойдёт

Comment: Сделал как у вас, все равно получаю то же самое в логах

Comment: @vp_arth вы не можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы зарегистрировали новый аккаунт? Нет, не могу. Я не понимаю, недостаточно данных.

Comment: @vp_arth Нет, у меня такая же проблема